# Extract all data before third space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pull all data before the third space...

```
var str = 'ORD - 1234567 Is the Order Number'
```

The result should be:

```
['ORD - 1234567']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) [Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string using space as a delimiter.

2) Take a [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) of the new array of the first 3 elements.

3) [Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the sliced array together again inserting the spaces.

4) Put the whole thing as the first element of `result`.

```
var result = [str.split(' ').slice(0,3).join(' ')];
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ggtym8np/)**

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following.

`str.split(" ").slice(0,3);`

This converts the string into an array of items split on each space. Then `.slice(0,3)` returns the first three items in the array. You can then use `join(" ")` to convert the three items into one string.

```js
var str = 'ORD - 1234567 Is the Order Number';
var result = [str.split(" ").slice(0,3).join(' ')];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split with a limit

```js
var str = 'ORD - 1234567 Is the Order Number'
var res = [str.split(' ',3).join(' ')];

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about the `limit` option.